# How can you reset an expire date for Windows?

Tags: windows-10

This is for Windows 10, and I'm nearing the end of the trial. 
I do know that there is a way. If this requires administrative access, how can you get that?

Comment: You can reset the expire date by purchasing a licence and activating Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on the edition you're running.

You could try to run [slmgr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502540(v=ws.11).aspx).

```
slmgr.vbs /rearm
```

Beware that this can only be done a limited number of times.